# Data type mismatch error using CDate function

Tags: ms-access, type-mismatch, calculated-field

I am trying to join a table to a query in MS Access. The field for the query is "LineoffMonth", and the field for the table is "Production Month". LineoffMonth looks like this:

LineoffMonth: CDate(Month([Line_off_Date]) & "/1/" & Year([Line_off_Date]))

Production Month is a date/time data type. I keep getting  "Data type mismatch error in expression". I do not understand why it will not let me join the two fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that error when `[Line_off_Date]` is Null as this Immediate window session illustrates.

```vb
Line_off_Date = Null
? Month(Line_off_Date) & "/1/" & Year(Line_off_Date)
/1/
? CDate("/1/") ' throws Type mismatch (Error 13)
```

You can update the table to replace Nulls in `[Line_off_Date]`.  Or you can add a `WHERE` clause to exclude rows which have Null for `[Line_off_Date]`.  Or you can use an `IIf` expression which returns the `CDate` expression when `[Line_off_Date]` is not Null, but something else (perhaps Null?) when `[Line_off_Date]` is Null.

As a side point, consider a `DateSerial` expression in place of what you were using.

```vb
Line_off_Date = Date()
? CDate(Month(Line_off_Date) & "/1/" & Year(Line_off_Date))
12/1/2013
? DateSerial(Year(Line_off_Date), Month(Line_off_Date), 1)
12/1/2013
```